# Converting a binary image file into a 224*224 image in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am reading an image (image size is Not 224*224) and it is this type:

```
def fetch_from_s3(client, image_s3url):
    bucket, key = image_s3url.split('/',2)[-1].split('/',1)
    result = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return result['Body'].read()
img =fetch_from_s3(client, image_s3url)
#
print(img)
>>
'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\....'
```

What I need: convert it into 224*224 image and then into numpy array.

I have a time consuming way to do it:

1. save it as an jpg file
2. convert the jpg into 224*224, and then into numpy array
3. delete this jpg file

Since I have millions of images to process, I wish to find a way to skip step 1 and 3 because they request a lot of extra time.

Is there a way to convert an arbitrary binary image file into numpy array that represent 224*224 image, directly ?

Comment: There are OS-dependent tools to resize files; I suspect that the best way for you is to convert the input directory using one of those; search using your OS name as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) or [cv2.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation))